# Combining multiple data files with header while also adding a data column

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, sed, cat

I have multiple tab delimited data files that are separated by month in the format `jan06.txt, feb06.txt, ..., dec07.txt`.

Within each file, it looks something like:

```
Header1 Header2 Header3 ...
Data1   Data2   Data3   ...
Data4   Data5   Data6   ...
...     ...     ...
```

What I want to do is to combine all all the data files into a single data file, with just a single header at the top, but also include a new data column that contains the month and year so I don't lose that information from the file name. So my new, single data file would contain:

```
Date   Header1 Header2 Header3 ...
200601 Data1   Data2   Data3   ...
200602 Data4   Data5   Data6   ...
...    ...     ...     ...
```

Where 200601 would refer to Jan 06, 200602 refer to Feb 06, etc.

I know if I do something like `cat *.txt > data.txt`, I could combine all my files. However, the two issues remain:

1. I have a header in every file that would get concatenated, which I don't want.
2. I would lose the month information that is stored in the file name.

I think I can do this with some combination of `cat` and `sed`, but I am not sure how to start.

Comment: (I'm not any good with script, I just wondered...) how do you want the data compressed (for lack of a better term) into a single data file? It appears to me that 200601,Header1 would have lots of data entries the old way and only 1 the new way.

Comment: @MarcusChan I added more to my question description above so hopefully that helps. But to explain more, for `jan06.txt` I would want 200601 appended to a new data column on the left side for *every* row entry for `jan01.txt`. For `feb06.txt`, I would want 200602 appended to every row. I would then want all of those rows together in one data file with just a single header at the top.

Comment: also asked on [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14657638/7552)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an awk program that should do what you need:

```
awk '
    BEGIN {
        # create an array so we can map the month number to month name
        split("jan feb mar apr may jun jul aug sep oct nov dec", months)
    }
    function filename2date(filename,         month, year, i) {
        month = substr(filename, 1, 3)
        year = substr(filename, 4, 2)
        for (i=1; i<=12; i++) 
            if (months[i] == month) 
                return sprintf("20%s%02d", year, i)
        return filename
    }
    NR == 1  { 
        # this is the first line of the first file
        print "Date", $0 
    }
    FNR == 1 { 
        # this is the first line of each file
        date = filename2date(FILENAME)
        next
    }
    { print date, $0 }
' ???[0-9][0-9].txt > data.txt
```